# Encoding inappropriate Characters

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, decoding, utf8-decode

How can I get it printed just what is written in code? `ışık hğzmesi` is written at code and I want to it printed again as `ışık hğzmesi`. What i have tried below about utf-8 coding they haven't work. My code editor set-up is also utf-8.

```
<?php
    $t = 'ışık hğzmesi';
    echo utf8_encode($t);

result:Ã„Â±Ã…ÂŸÃ„Â±k hÃ„ÂŸzmesi
?>


<?php
    $t = 'ışık hüzmesi';
    echo utf8_decode(($t));

//result:???k hüzmesi
?>

<?php
    $t = 'ışık hüzmesi';
    echo urlencode($t);

//result:%C4%B1%C5%9F%C4%B1k+h%C3%BCzmesi
?>


<?php
    $t = 'ışık hüzmesi';
    echo urldecode(urlencode($t));

//result:Ä±ÅŸÄ±k hÃ¼zmesi
?>
```

Comment: You probably just have to [specify the character encoding properly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2).

Answer (score 1):

The physical encoding of the source file is UTF-8, therefore the strings are already UTF-8. Never use `utf8_encode`.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$t = 'ışık hğzmesi';
echo $t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this as the very first thing in your code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```